# Doctype vs. html design

Tags: html, doctype

i got this piece of code:

```
 <head>
 <title>width height</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="800px">
     <tr>
         <td style="height: 100px">
             cucu
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="height: 100%">
         <td class="tdMargin" style="width: 760px">
         bau    
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td style="height:50px" valign="bottom">
            bla
         </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

it behaves how it should

i added it in a masterpage, it works all right

but when i take the doctype stuff from the old masterpage (we are redesigning the app)
and add the:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to the page, the design (height 100% stuff) goes mad

is there a way to fix it?

i don't know too much about doctypes ...

it should basically work in IE, if that helps

Comment: Why the need to use XHTML in the first place? It's a very restrictive doctype.

Comment: Definitely use a doctype, it will save you hours of frustration down the road... but it doesn't need to be so strict. I'd recommend the HTML5 one. `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: @Pekka problem is that i am using some ajax control toolkit stuff in there and if i remember correctly, we had some problems with the tabpanels from that, and this doctype was the only one that made it look ok. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look : [HTML  Declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp)

> The doctype declaration is not an HTML
>   tag; it is an instruction to the web
>   browser about what version of the
>   markup language the page is written
>   in.

The DocType you are using seems to be incorrect or restrictive. Please set it as per the HTML version you are using.

Comment: In principle correct, but there is no doctype that can be used with that HTML. Applying any valid doctype to the page will make the browser render it in standards compliant mode, and the height attribute of the table will be ignored.

Comment: so basically, there's no way i can fix the height ?

Answer (score 0):

The height settings *should* be ignored, the browser behaves exactly as expected.

There is no `height` attribute for the `table` element in the standard. It's only Internet Explorer that thinks that there is, and it only does so in quirks mode (i.e. when there is no doctype).

Use a CSS style to set the height of the table instead:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800px" style="height: 100%;">
```

Preferrably the CSS should go in a style sheet, not in the separate elements, but I show the style that way here so that you can test it easily.

Comment: i made the changes what you said, yes that's how it should be used, it works the same as my code. but the doctype messes it up the same way

Comment: you were saying that the  the height attribute of the table will be ignored. you mean height = 100% or style=height:100% ? or both ?

Comment: @Swoosh: The `height` attribute will be ignored. Using `style` to set the height is valid. You may however need to set the height of the `html` and `body` elements to 100% too, as they work differently in XHTML.